# How can I rename sql file name at bigquery?

Tags: google-bigquery

How can I rename sql file name at bigquery?
In left explorer, I can't find rename menu
I'm using bigquery for enterprise. but I can't recognize that UI

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Spb9p.png)

I try to find menu, however I can't find it

Comment: I think you can only use "Save query As" to save the file with a new name and then just delete the current version of the file.